# Thunder Client: Run collection/request multiple times with delay

Tags: vscode-extensions, thunderclient

What is the easiest way to run collection/request multiple time (best with delay) using Thunder Client (or its cli)

Aiming for similar usage as in Postman Collection Runner or newman:
`npx newman run my.postman_collection.json --delay-request 2000 -n 200`

I checked docs and internet :) but is hard to find this kind examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the collection, and select `Run All` menu item and you will see all the options for delay, iterations etc

Comment: Perfect. Additional question: is possible to select items to run?

Comment: If you like run selected requests, you can run CLI. Please see our Cli documentation. 

Please reach out on our GitHub page if you have any questions